# numkeys not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, numpad

I have recently shifted to ubuntu 18.04. Since I shifted , my numkeys are not working . What can be done regarding this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but is NumLock active?

Comment: If you have NumLock on,  if you hold down the 2 button and your mouse pointer move on the screen, you need to disable Mouse Keys in Settings > Universal Access.